how to check which HDFS datanode ip is returned by namenode to spark?
If I'm reading/writing a dataframe in PySpark specifying HDFS name node hostname and port:
 df.write.parquet("hdfs://namenode:8020/test/go", mode="overwrite")

Is there any way to debug which specific datanode(s) host/ports are returned to Spark by that namenode?

I only needed to set the Spark log level to debug.
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

